# How to setting the padding to 0 for content area in antdpro

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

[image]

Hi guys,
I had one frondend project based on antdpro (Ant Design Pro 5.0.0), when I add one page, the padding is default as above pic.

How could I remove these padding ？
Due to the space is not enough, I hope set the padding to 0.

BTW:  the offical  http://preview.pro.ant.design  can find this situation as well, So I don't provide my own test code.

Comment: Does this help ? https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/9173

Comment: it help me verify much, that is what I want exactly. Thanks you verify much

Answer (score 0):

Please set this margin to 0 and it will remove space around. Please check attach screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, This is a common method to resolve all css issue. So does my question.

Answer (score 0):

As Gabriele Petrioli Said, the most direct method is adjust one parameter at app.js
`disableContentMargin: true`

[image]

The another common way to resolve all css issue is said as Yash Jain.
I can do it via follow pic
[image]

Thanks again to  @Gabriele Petrioli and @Yash Jain